# How to provide saml single logout without a private key in c#

Tags: c#

Can anyone provide the solution for **single signout** for my application as well as for **gsuite(saml)** in c#?

I had a x509.certificate with no private key. Is there any possibility to provide a support for single signout?

Comment: As an SP or IDP?

Comment: It is IDP provider.